# How to use git commit count to find the corresponding commit?

Tags: git, versioning

When I use  `git rev-list --count HEAD` revision as part of my EXE's version info...

I wonder how to find the commit when I only have the count value.

For instance,
`git rev-list --count HEAD` returns 50 and the commit is "abcdefg...."

With the commits growing, use `git rev-list --count HEAD` again and return 100,

How can I use **50** to find "abcdefg...." easily?

I try to find the answer but I didn't find out any clue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The *general* answer is that you can't.  (This is why version information should be produced by `git describe`, rather than by counting commits directly.)

In some *specific cases*, `HEAD~50` would get you what you want.

The reason the general answer is "you can't" is that `--count` gives you a single, linear measure: the number of commits encountered on a walk of some portion of the commit graph, as given by the constraints you passed to `git rev-list`.  This *loses information*, because the graph itself may contain more commits than are counted based on the restrictions passed, and because the count of commits reached in any given walk depends not only on the number of commits *in* the graph, but also the *shape of the walk*.

Consider, for instance, this graph:

```
A--B--C   <-- branch1

D--E--F   <-- branch2
```

This graph arises from use of `git checkout --orphan` or `git switch --orphan` or several other possibilities.  Running `git rev-list --count branch1` will produce 3, as that's the number of commits traversed by starting at commit `C` and working backwards.

If we now use `git checkout branch1; git merge --allow-unrelated-histories branch2` to make a new merge commit `G` that ties both sub-graphs together, we get:

```
A--B--C--G   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
        /
 D--E--F   <-- branch2
```

Running `git rev-list --count branch1` now produces the number 7.  But we only want to step back 1, not 4, commits to reach commit `G`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `git rev-list --count` does not "number" each commit one after the previous one, but makes the total of all commits it can find back starting from given position(s).

`rev-list` is actually a kind of "plumbing" command meant to retrieve all these commits, and `--count` is a convenient way to sum them while fetching them, rather than having to count them yourself using external and dirty trick to achieve this.

This is especially true when passing more than one branch, for instance `git rev-list --count a b`

```
  a o   o b
    |   |
    o   o
    |   |
    o   o
    |   |
    o   o
     \ /
      o
      |
      o
      |
      I
```

In this last example, you'll get a total of 11 commits, including initial one.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in other answers : the short answer is "you can't".

Take the following example :

```
*--*--*--*--a--*--*
       \         /
        --*--b---
```

Both `a` and `b` will have a "commit count" of 5. In actual repos, this may amount to many more commits which have the same count of ancestors.

On top of that, if a history rewriting operation was performed, your original commit may well be not here anymore.

It is much more convenient to store the sha of the commit that lead to the build (that way you have a direct reference to that commit, and if it disappeared at least you will know !), and to place tags in your repo to point at commits which lead to a build.

---

That being said, you may have other criteria to narrow your search (e.g : if your builds are only made from `master`, you can probably look at `git log --first-parent master`), and you can search for at least one commit which has the correct count.

One blunt way is to compute `git rev-list --count` for each commit in your history :

```
# you can search within the history of `master` if you know it is relevant,
# or in 'rev-list --first-parent master'
# or in 'rev-list --all' if you want to look for any commit in your repo
git rev-list master | while read sha; do count=$(git rev-list --count $sha); echo "$sha count=$count"; done

# if you are looking for count=50 :
... | grep 'count=50'
```

Or you can use `git bisect` :

- create a script with checks `git rev-list --count` :

```
# file test.sh :

#!/bin/bash

test $(git rev-list --count HEAD) -lt 50
```

- make sure your current HEAD has too many commits (e.g : is a "bad" commit)
- spot a commit which has less than 50 parents (any such commit will do, it will be your initial "good" commit)
- run git bisect :

```
git bisect start
git bisect bad HEAD
git bisect good <that other commit>

git bisect run ./test.sh
```

When `git bisect` completes, you should be on a commit, whose parent count is 50.